# kdb - how to create sum a list of dynamic columns using functional select

Tags: kdb

I want to be able to construct `` (+; (+; `a; `b); `c) `` given a list of `` `a`b`c ``

Similarly if I have a list of `` `a`b`c`d ``, I want to be able to construct another nest and so on and so fourth.

I've been trying to use scan but I cant get it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
q)fsum:(+;;)/
enlist[+;;]/

q)fsum `a`b`c`d
+
(+;(+;`a;`b);`c)
`d
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the raw parse tree output, one way is to form the equivalent string and use `parse`. This isn't recommended for more complex examples, but in this case it is clear.

```
{parse "+" sv string x}[`a`b`c`d]
+
`d
(+;`c;(+;`b;`a))
```

If you are looking to use this in a functional select, we can use `+/` instead of adding each column individually, like how you specified in your example

```
q)parse"+/[(a;b;c;d)]"
(/;+)
(enlist;`a;`b;`c;`d)

q)f:{[t;c] ?[t;();0b;enlist[`res]!enlist (+/;(enlist,c))]}; 
q)t:([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6;c:7 8 9;d:10 11 12)

q)f[t;`a`b`c]
res
---
12 
15 
18 

q)f[t;`a`b]
res
---
5  
7  
9  

q)f[t;`a`b`c]~?[t;();0b;enlist[`res]!enlist (+;(+;`a;`b);`c)]
1b
```

You can also get the sum by indexing directly to return a list of each column values and sum over these. We use `(),` to turn any input into a list, otherwise it will sum the values in that single column and return only a single value

```
q)f:{[t;c] sum t (),c}
q)f[t;`a`b`c]
12 15 18
```